# Is there a way to know if a script was successfully loaded?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, callback, action

In my plugin, I use the wordpress core plupload srcipt:

```
function plug_enqueue_scripts() { 
   wp_enqueue_script( 'plupload-all' ); //wordpress core
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'plug_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Is there a way to know if the script was successfully loaded? a callback fct? A return value?

If the script fail to load, I want to include my own plupload (js and css).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_script_is()` to check the status of a script:

```
if( false === wp_script_is( 'plupload-all', 'enqueued' ) ){
    // script not enqueued, do stuff
}
```

If you want to check if the script has been actually printed use `done` instead of `enqueued` for the second param. See all accepted values in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is).